# An inverse z-transform

Tags: inverse, z-transform

I did the inverse z-transform of $\frac{2}{z+1/3}$ and got a result, by doing so

$$\mathscr{Z}^{-1}\{\frac{2}{z+1/3}\}=2\lim_{z_0\longrightarrow -1/3}(z+1/3)\frac{z^{n-1}}{z+1/3}=2\lim_{z_0\longrightarrow -1/3} z^{n-1}=2(-1/3)^{n-1}$$

But another source, claims this is the right result:

$$2(-1/3)^{n-1}\Theta(n-1)$$

Why should this result with the Heaviside function be correct, when the formula for the inverse transform  is given by the contour integral:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C x(z)z^{n-1}dz$$

Thanks

Comment: Since $\frac{2}{z}\frac{1}{1+1/(3z)}$ only has positive powers of $1/z$, you need a $\Theta(n-1)$ factor. The crux of your question is where you make a hidden $n\ge1$ assumption in your calculation of the IZT as a function of $n$. But the contour integral makes obvious why this requirement applies for a nonzero result: if $n\le0$, the integrand lacks a $1/z$ term.

Comment: Maybe it is difficult to explain it, but I didn't understand your answer, although I suspect it is correct. Is there another way to explain it, i.e. a counterexample of when NOT to use $\Theta(n-1)$?

Comment: [It comes down to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Definition) whether your transform is bilateral or unilateral. But for the former, you need to carefully consider convergence.

Comment: I see now, but in this exercise, it does not say anything about the domain of $z$. Since it is signal analysis, should I always assume bilateral? Then it would necessary get that Heavisde function $\Theta(n-1)$ to the solution of method by residues.